# Maven fails to find an artifact installed locally, that only exists installed locally

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

This is a bit different that the existing questions with similar errors - I do not think this is a duplicate.

I have project A which I successfully build and installed locally with `mvn clean install`.

I verified the jar and pom exist in the director `~/.m2/com/example/A/1.0/` and they are not corrupt.

Project B uses project A as a dependency.  Simple enough:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I attempt to build B, I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project B: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:B:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failure to find com.example:A:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I cleaned out the files `_remote.repositories` and `_maven.repositories` that I read are the failure caches.

Problem still occurs.   My maven version is 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delete directory ~/.m2/com/example/A/1.0/ and reinstall A ,then you build B with -U option.

Comment: If you delete the folder no supplemental option is needed.